# Azure Data Factory - loop through parametrized linked service?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline job that pulls data from an API linked service and inserts it into a SQL table via the copy data activity.

The base URL for the API is below

https://api.test.com/v3/contacts/14299157/contactStats?startDate=2022-10-01&endDate=2022-11-03

I have a SQL table that looks like the below..

```
 ContactID              StartDate              EndDate
     1                  01-jan-2020           01-jan-2021
     1                  01-jan-2022           01-jan-2023
```

Is it possible to run a loop on this? So I want it to reference my SQL table and run the API for the first row which would look like this..
https://api.test.com/v3/contacts/1/contactStats?startDate=2020-01-01&endDate=2021-01-01
and output the data into a table. It would then run again for the next row..
https://api.test.com/v3/contacts/1/contactStats?startDate=2022-01-01&endDate=2023-01-01

and also output this data to my table, until it has finished all of the rows in my SQL table.

How would I go about setting this up? Can someone please explain if this is doable?

Comment: nevermind.. this video helped me
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gCz-LlBGrIA

Comment: how you are getting this rest api's that to be looped?

Answer (score 0):

> How would I go about setting this up? Can someone please explain if this is doable?

**UPDATED ANSWER:**

To loop on parameterized linked service, we need to pass the list of API's or modify the res Api dynamically as per your requirement and to for each loop.

- First take Lookup activity and get the table data from SQL.
  [image]
- Then pass that lookup Output to Foreach activity `@activity('Lookup1').output.value`. [image]
- Create linked service for Rest API And divide your URL to base URL and Relative URL as blow enter your `https://api.test.com/v3/contacts/` as base URL.
  [image]
- Then go to that dataset and create dataset Parameter
  [image]- Enter relative URL as `@concat(dataset().contactId,'/contactStats?startDate=',dataset().Startdate,'&endDate=',dataset().Enddate)`  With dynamic parameters
  [image]
- Under ForEach loop take a copy activity and select the source as Rest API and pass dynamic value foreach activity item as `@item().ContactId`,`@item().StartDate`,`@item().EndDate` respectively for each dataset parameter.
  [image]

**Looping API:**
[image]

Comment: Answer is updated please take a look.